# Vim binding to wrap word under cursor in double curly braces

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, surround

When working with Jinja templates and YAML for Ansible configuration, I often copy+paste a variable name (say, `nginx_root`) and then need to wrap it in double curly braces: `{{ nginx_root }}`. This gets cumbersome to do manually, so I want to be able to type a Vim key binding to wrap the current word under the cursor in double curly braces.

Using the [vim-surround plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround), I can add the desired curly braces to the word under the cursor via `ysiw}lysiw{`, but that is many more key strokes than I would prefer. I have tried the following Vim key binding, but invoking it in normal mode has no visible effect at all:

```
" Wrap text under cursor with double curly braces (e.g., for Jinja variables)
nnoremap <C-J> ysiw}lysiw{
```

Ergo, my questions are:

1. Using stock Vim functionality, the [vim-surround plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround), and/or any other combination of tooling, how can one bind a key that will wrap the current word under the cursor with space-padded double curly braces? e.g., `nginx_root` → `{{ nginx_root }}`
2. Is there a way to also achieve this in insert mode, with the cursor just to the right of the word? (`nginx_root*`, where `*` is the cursor position)
3. How would one bind a key (preferably available in both normal and insert modes) to insert `{{ * }}` at the current cursor position, where `*` is the position of the cursor after insertion? (This would facilitate entering new Jinja variables, versus operating on copy+pasted variables as noted above.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Fixing your mapping

Your mapping does not work because it uses `:noremap`. It is correct to avoid remapping (via the `nore` part of the command) as much as possible, but as you're invoking surround.vim's `ys` mapping in there, there's no (easy) way around it:

```
nmap <C-J> ysiw}lysiw{
```

#### A surround.vim alternative

That double surrounding is awkward, and actually not necessary, because the plugin allows to define custom replacements, as per `:help surround-customizing`.

The following defines a new replacement on `d` (for "double"; `100 = char2nr('d')`); with it, you can add double curlies to a word via `ysiwd`:

```
let g:surround_100 = "{{ \r }}"
```

To only define the mapping for certain filetype(s), replace the `g:` with `b:`. I would recommend putting this then into `~/.vim/ftplugin/{filetype}_whatever.vim` (or `{filetype}/whatever.vim`; cp. `:help ftplugin-name`) instead of defining lots of `:autocmd FileType {filetype} ...`; it's cleaner and scales better; requires that you have `:filetype plugin on`, though.

#### Your other questions

The surround.vim plugin also offers an insert mode `<C-g>s` mapping. I would recommend against insert mode mappings for these kinds of edits; it's against Vim's mode-based model, and only few (and awkward key combinations with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>) keys are available there.

To insert a template, a simple mapping will do. You can position the cursor in between the added curlies via the special `<Left>` keys:

```
:nnoremap <C-g>d a{{  }}<Left><Left><Left>
:inoremap <C-g>d {{  }}<Left><Left><Left>
```

Comment: Brilliant suggestions! While not as clean/scalable, for the wrapper I opted for a one-liner: `autocmd FileType ansible,ansible_template,htmljinja,htmldjango let b:surround_100 = "{{ \r }}"`

Comment: Yeah, in that case, nothings beats the conciseness of that one-liner! If this answers your question, please don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: Accepted! Thanks for the detailed and spot-on answers. You rock!

Answer (score 0):

In order to execute normal mode commands, try

```
nnoremap <C-J> :normal ysiw}lysiw{<CR>
```

See `:help normal` for details.

Comment: That works, but it addresses the problem in a very roundabout way. Just switching to `:nmap` is enough.